# Stripe - You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it has already succeeded after being previously confirmed

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a simple setup of charging customers with my merchant, where I am creating a payment intent like this:

first I pass the stripe promise like this:

```
const stripe_promise = loadStripe(publishableKey, {
            stripeAccount: business.stripe_account_id,
});
```

And then include:

```
{stripePromise && amount && business && (
         <Elements stripe={stripePromise}  > 
            <ApplePay  amount={amount} business={business} businessId={businessId} />
         </Elements>
)}
```

And then on the ApplePay component:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(!stripe || !elements || !props.amount || !props.business){
            return;
        }
 

        const payReq = stripe.paymentRequest({
            currency: 'gbp',
            country: 'GB',
            requestPayerEmail: true,
            requestPayerName: true,
            total: {
                label: business_name,
                amount: total_amount, 
            },
        });

        payReq.canMakePayment().then((result) => {

            if(result){
                setPaymentRequest(payReq);
            }
        }); 
        
        console.log('account id :', connected_account_id);
        console.log('Pay Reqest', payReq);

        // Complete the payment
        payReq.on('paymentmethod', async (e) => {

            // console.log('payment method :', e.paymentMethod); 
            
            // create a payment intent on server
            const { error: backendError, clientSecret } = await fetch("/api/stripe/create-payment-intent", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({  
                    amount: total_amount, 
                    CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID: connected_account_id,
                    payment_method_id: e.paymentMethod.id
                }),
              }).then(res => res.json());

            if(backendError){
                e.complete('Payment Failed');
                console.log(backendError);
                alert('Payment Failed!');
                return;
            }
            
            // confirm the payment intent on the client
            const { error, paymentIntent } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
                clientSecret, {
                    payment_method: e.paymentMethod.id,
                }, 
                {
                   handleActions: false,
                },
                {
                    stripeAccount: connected_account_id, 
                }
            );

            if(error){
                e.complete('fails');
                alert('Payment Failed');
                return;
            }

            
            if(paymentIntent.status == 'requires_action'){
                stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret);
                e.complete('success');
                router.push('/pay/'+business_id+'/thanks');

            }else{
                e.complete('success');
                router.push('/pay/'+business_id+'/thanks');
            }
        });

    },[stripe, elements, props]);
```

But when a customer does a transaction this is the error generated on Stripe developers logs:

```
payment_intent_unexpected_state
You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it has already succeeded after being previously confirmed.
```

Comment: It seems that you are confirming the same PaymentMethod twice. Try debug your integration and check the status of the PaymentIntent returned from your endpoint `/api/stripe/create-payment-intent`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that many times in my own usage of Stripe; AFAIK that's just normal and harmless(all it does is create that log and prints to the browser console), it's just a quirk of the integration of the PaymentRequestButton(since it confirms the PaymentIntent twice in order to properly handle some complexities of the wallets+3D Secure). You can just ignore the errors since it doesn't actually stop the customer from paying or present any customer-visible error.